# Qodana - how to set IncorrectHttpHeaderInspection in custom yaml profile

Tags: qodana

I am trying to create a custom Qodana profile to add custom Http headers to the allowed set. I have autogenerated an xml file in IntelliJ, which looks like this:

```xml
<component name="InspectionProjectProfileManager">
  <profile version="1.0">
    <option name="myName" value="Project Default" />
    ...
    <inspection_tool class="IncorrectHttpHeaderInspection" enabled="true" level="WARNING" enabled_by_default="true">
      <option name="customHeaders">
        <set>
          <option value="my-header-1" />
          <option value="my-header-2" />
          <option value="my-header-3" />
        </set>
      </option>
    </inspection_tool>
  </profile>
</component>
```

This works in my local IntelliJ environment, and I'd like to translate this into my custom Qodana profile yaml file. I have tried following the guide here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/qodana/custom-profiles.html#Configuration+examples, but I cannot get it to work. My code looks like this:

**qodana.yaml**

```yaml
version: "1.0"
linter: jetbrains/qodana-jvm-community:latest
failThreshold: 0
profile:
  path: .qodana/profiles/profile.yaml
```

**.qodana/profiles/profile.yaml**

```yaml
name: "My qodana profile"

baseProfile: qodana.recommended

inspections:
  - inspection: IncorrectHttpHeaderInspection
    options:
      customHeaders: 
        - "my-header-1"
        - "my-header-2"
        - "my-header-3"
```

I think the issue lies with the `<set>` operator in the xml file, but I haven't been able to see any examples of how to translate this to the correct yaml format, so I'm left with guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently yaml profiles don't support setting such options. Here is [a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/QD-8468/Support-lists-in-inspection-options-in-yaml-profiles) for it on the Qodana issue tracker.
You can [create an XML profile](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/qodana/custom-xml-profiles.html) of your own, enable and configure required inspections, export it, and then [use it in Qodana](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/qodana/inspection-profiles.html#Profile+path) instead of the yaml one to make it work.